# HDR-fusion - when to use what method?

Tags: hdr

I am studying different methods for hdr-fusion in the opencv-tutorial here:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/df0/tutorial_py_hdr.html

I am also reading various articles. However, I don't seem to find any information on when I such use which method, i.e. some overview of the pros and cons of each method. The methods are Debevec, Robertson, Mertens fusion. And the tonemapping methods are TonemapDrago, TonemapMantiuk and TonemapReinhard.

Does anybode know how to choose the right method without a week of trial and error?